# Ruby on rails? The choice of web application framework with oracle backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle

I am trying to research the best language / framework to use to solve my problem. I have started looking very closely at Ruby on Rails but was wondering if some of you might be able to shed some light on why this might be a good or not a good choice.

What I need is to develop a web application that can be built upon an existing oracle database. I need it to be secure but would ideally I do not want to write my own user permission / authentication logic. Instead would like to have a customizable one that I can leverage off of. I have seen ruby on rails have many 'gems' that look like this would not be a problem.

Secondly I need something that I can easily reuse code for CRUD functionality on data sets. Most of this application will revolve around the users being able to edit records etc.

Lastly and most importantly, this needs to work with an existing Oracle back-end. As I started to read about ruby it seemed that hooking it up with Oracle might cause some issues. One concern I had was it seemed that you needed to install Oracle on your machine in order for it to work, my database is not on my machine but on a different server and I would prefer not to have to install oracle but rather just connect to my development server's database... is this possible?

Thank you for your input and help.

Comment: Do you k now where the restriction that Oracle has to be on the same machine comes from?

Comment: No idea, I am not even sure this is accurate. I was just reading from a couple sources that if you try and insall the oci8 gem, if you don't have oracle on your machine it might cause issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [Oracle Application Express (APEX)](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html)?  Sounds like a perfect fit to me.

Comment: ehh, that is what I am using, and desperately trying to get away from. While oracle apex allows you to easily do crud functions on tables, to me it is a nightmare to develop in. It seems very restricting when you try and customize anything with the UI.

Comment: Customising is getting easier all the time.  What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: I guess there's the question of whether your priority is easy CRUD development or more customisable UI. ApEx is going to be naturally resistant to SQL injection, uses Oracle very efficiently (for the same reason -- it uses bind variables, which are generally more trouble in other development systems), gives enterprise-class authentication, etc.

Comment: 4.1 the latest. I have been trying to develop a mobile version of my application and it has been terrible. I am trying to use the latest version of jQuery mobile (see my other posts). And it is not playing nicely at all. Also creating custom templates does not seem that great to me in apex. Sometimes I find myself hardcoding things into the template because of the way apex reacts if I try and manipulate it my rendered page with say javascript.

Comment: Have you seen: http://www.oracle-and-apex.com/hidden-mobile-support-in-oracle-apex-4-1/ and http://www.oracle-and-apex.com/mobile-oracle-apex-on-your-smartphone/ etc?

Comment: @David Aldrige yes I have read those. They are using jQuery mobile 1.04a.1. The current version is now at 1.1 and some major bugs have been solved since then. Oracle Apex does not play nicely with any version after 1.04a.1 for some reason. I can't get any pages to render if using another other than this version.

Comment: Better mobile support coming in 4.2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-sod-087560.html

Answer (score 1):

First off I will start by saying that I haven't used Ruby on rails so wouldn't be able to advise here. What I have read though is that in the past RoR may be considered over another platform such as javaee as it was considered easier to work(a one stop shop) and more lightweight. I'm not too sure whether this is the case now as java is in the process of stripping down its specs.

I would consider using **Java/javaEE(6)** platform in particular **JPA2** (data layer). This will allow you to use an ORM to map your database tables(relational model) to objects, **EJB3.1/managedbeans** (business layer which also helps with code re-use and concurrent data-access) and **JSF2** (a framework for creating UIs) **or JSP** as the presentation layer. There are many tutorials online and the majority of the documentation is published by Oracle.

I guess **security**-wise it is often the best idea to implement application server managed security as then you are relying on (hopefully) the fact that a security professional was consulted in the implementation of the app server. In a recent project I achieved this using Glassfish managed security which made it easy to **hook up existing user/roles** already stored in the database that would then control access to the application using URL patterns or whatever - a service like this is usually very customizable and may even have a GUI settings page in your chosen app server to aid in the configuration which will make life easier. Again this really depends on the application server you will use. It may be easier to integrate your oracle database with an oracle application server (WebLogic). There is likely to be similar functionality as to what I have explained about Glassfish.

You could also implement security at the EJB level which means that you can specify explicitly which roles can call which business methods. This may be over-kill but always something useful to bear in mind.

With regards to connecting to your database - would it not be easier to work with it using an IDE? Also, perhaps a useful feature for you as you already have the database made is to create your model entities from the database automatically using a tool. Netbeans supplies such functionality and it means that as long as you can connect remotely using the IDE you could create your data layer and a basic business layer with basic CRUD operations for each entity in <5 minutes (give or take). An understanding of the platform/relevant frameworks may take longer though.

Again check out some tutorials/docs on this. I'm pretty sure Netbeans can make your life easier if you are working with WebLogic as well.

Again sorry I can't shed any light on RoR. This is my personal suggestion and you may want to listen to others thoughts on the subject as well.